# How to update multiple fields (maxLength, maxBreadth or maxArea) of a document based on multiple conditions sent from req.body?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to store maximum length, breadth, area ever encountered from a request and store it in the database. In this case, anything can be maximum and based on that I want to update max values in the database for that particular field only.

```
const body = {
  oID: 123, // Primary key
  length: 50,
  breadth: 50
};
```

```
const { length, breadth } = body;
const currentArea = length * breadth;
```

```
await totalArea.updateOne(
  { oID: 123 },
  {
    $set: { $maxLength: maxLength < length ? length : $maxLength }, // I want to update the docs based on mongo query only since this won't work.
    $set: { $maxBreadth: maxBreadth < breadth ? breadth : $maxBreadth },  // I want to update the docs based on mongo query only since this won't work.
    $set: { $maxArea: maxArea < currentArea ? currentArea : $maxArea }  // I want to update the docs based on mongo query only since this won't work.
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

In the above example, I have demonstrated the logic using ternary operator and I want to perform the same operation using mongoDB query. i.e update a particular field while comparing it to existing fields from the database and update it if it satisfies the condition.

Comment: `$max` operator https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-maximum-operator-max/#:~:text=MongoDB%20provides%20different%20types%20of,greater%20than%20the%20current%20value.

Comment: @MehariMamo, I tried using max but one field gets updated and other doesn't, can you kindly demonstrate me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await totalArea.updateOne(
  { oID: 123
      },
      {
        $max: {
          maxLength: length,
          maxBreadth: breadth,
          maxArea : currentArea
        }
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

I found this to be working correctly. Thanks to @Mehari Mamo's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  oID: 123
},
[{$set: {maxLength: {$max: [length, "$maxLength"]},
         maxBreadth: {$max: [breadth, "$maxBreadth"]},
         maxArea : {$max: [currentArea, "$maxArea "]}
      }
    }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

You can check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lTTtguo2QnG) .

The `[]` on the second step allows you to access the current values of the document fields, as this is an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I found a simpler query based on @Mehari Mamo's comment so I am updating my version of answer.

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting here?

Comment: @yaxx, based on the above code also works fine.